# PHP scraping thwarted by redirects

Tags: php, dom, scrape

I am trying to convert a library search engine to a mobile friendly site in a php script. The plan is to scrape the results and present a simplified form, as the site only looks good in a large browser at the moment.

I am having a little trouble using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net because everytime I try to load a query by loading this page `www.librarywebsite.com/search.php?query=BOOKTITLE` it goes through several redirects and then presents a final results page which has a similar set of parameters in the url but which, if refreshed, insists on the redirect anyway.

Does anyone know how to perform a DOM scrape only after all redirects have been completed?

Comment: they have there own mobile project, perhaps they don't want you stealing their data

Comment: If they have one already I wouldn't be bothering. Can you show me where?

Comment: bottom of page you linked to, it says one is coming soon

Comment: @Dagon I think that message is quite old (2yrs+)

Comment: could do something crazy and talk to them i'm sure they would help you if they don't have a mobile project of their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using something like cURL with follow redirects enabled. I believe the cURL option is **CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION**. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php